# Is it possible to query data from the Survey Invitations and Responses list via Apex Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, survey

Essentially I was thinking about using *Apex Trigger* to set the latest "**Invitation Link**" to a field, so that I can populate the survey link to the Classic Email Template.

[image]

**Additional:**

Would it be possible to accomplish? Or are there better/easier methods to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I tried using Flows, now I'm looking into Triggers

Comment: If Flows don't work then trigger is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this with a trigger. Note that there are two different objects combined together in that related list: `SurveyResponse` and `SurveyInvitation`. If you are trying to get the invitation link then you will need to use the `SurveyInvitation` object.

I would suggest checking Trailhead for a tutorial on how to do a trigger: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers

Comment: Ok, and should the trigger be created in the Opportunity or Survey Invitation object?

Comment: Survey Invitation. Your trigger should run when a survey invitation is inserted, updated, deleted or undeleted. It will then update the opportunity.